# Unable to retrieve value from PouchDB

Tags: couchdb, indexeddb, pouchdb

After inserting data using PouchDB I tried `db.getAll()` to retrieve all the documents and `db.get()` for single documents but none of the objects returned contained the value I was inserted in.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
new Pouch('idb://test', function(err, db) {
  doc = {
    test : 'foo',
    value : 'bar'
  }

  db.post(doc, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
      else console.log(data)
  })

  db.allDocs(function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
      else console.log(data)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your *allDocs* query is running before you have completed inserting the data into PouchDB, due to the IndexedDB API all database queries are asynchronous (they likely would have to be anyway as it's also a HTTP client).

```
new Pouch('idb://test', function(err, db) {
  var doc = {
    test : 'foo',
    value : 'bar'
  };
  db.post(doc, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    db.allDocs(function(err, data){
      if (err)    console.err(err)
      else console.log(data)
    });
  });
});
```

... should work.

Comment: Got it ! And yes the async part was causing it. Thanks:)